# Prevent hotlinking on gitlab pages

Tags: hotlinking, gitlab-pages

We host a website via GitLab Pages (static website generation) and have recently encountered a problem.
In the licence for our fonts (or in the installation details) it is mentioned that we should take measures to prevent hotlinking (e.g. not being able to download the font directly).

Usually this is done via entries in a config or htaccess file that prevent direct access if the referrer is not the domain.
But I couldn't find any information on how to do this with gitlab pages, so I wonder if this is even possible and if so how can it be done?

I'm still new to asking questions on stackoverflow and haven't found any questions about this, so apologies if I've missed something.

Thanks in advance.